# Where can I find domain settings for Rails jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I'm on Rails 5.2
Trying to send messages through ActiveJob. Everything is fine, nevertheless when I try to make an url with a helper (like `image_tag(user.avatar, class: "avatar")`) for image inside job's method, it sets url's domain to "http://example.org".

Other Rails parts use the correct name, but jobs seem to retrieve a default setting from a config file (I guess).

Could you give me a clue where to find it? Or maybe I have to put a magick line somewhere in configs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the default host in your environment config:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # ...
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'preview.mydomain.com'
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
  # ...
end
```

include the URL helpers in your job class:

```
class MyJob
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def perform(*args)
    # your image tage goes here
  end
end
```